# OData filter for SharePoint Online libraries stopped working

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-online

We use SharePoint Online RESP API in our applications. One of the calls we use is:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives?$filter=name eq '{driveName}'&$select=id
```

to get library ID based on it's name. This worked fine until Saturday 8/26. After that it suddenly ignores the OData filter and returns all libraries. What is worse that it blocks our users from using our applications. Is this some sort of change in the API? It looks like a bug to me. Is there any way how to report a bug or how to contact the dev team?

We reported it on Office 365 Business support but it was not very helpful as they claim that they cannot help with 'development issues'.